# javascript/jquery extract Html-text  from HTML table containing input tags 

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a big problem. I want to extract text from html table that contains input tags, raw text, link tags etc. and display in a new window clean html table with only text.

SAMPLE INPUT

```
<TABLE id="test">
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD>TEXT 1</TD>
<TD><a href="/questions">TEXT 2</a></TD>
<TD><input  type="text" value="TEXT 3" ></TD>
</TR>
</TBODY>
</TABLE>
```

magic things(script) happen(parse) here(this)

OUTPUT

```
<TABLE  id="test">
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD>TEXT 1</TD>
<TD>TEXT 2</TD>
<TD>TEXT 3</TD>
</TR>
</TBODY>
</TABLE>
```

I searched almost everywhere and i cannot get it to work. 
I need this functionality for copy paste.

Any Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @artlung

Based on your sample i prepared complete solution 
(copy paste to html file)

**And im asking for reviewing this, maybe it can be done better?**

Complete problem:

1.Transform HTML table with inputs,anchor, text to new CLEAN Html table with only text

2.Create new window and transfer prepared Table

**SOLUTION:**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>TEST HTML table with inputs , anchor to text </title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var tmp = '';

$('table tbody tr').each(function () {   //iterate tr
tmp += '<tr>';  
$(this ).find('td').each(function () {  //iterate td
    tmp += '<td>';
    tmp += $(this).text();
    $(this).find('input').each(function () {
            tmp += $(this).val() ;
        tmp += '</td>'; 
    });
});
tmp += '</tr>'; 
});


$("#demo_button").click(function(e) {
myWindow=window.open('','MyNewWindow','width=500,height=300,left=200,top=100');
myWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>CTRL+C to copy</title></head><body><table><tbody>'  + tmp +  '</tbody></table></body></html>');
myWindow.document.close();
myWindow.focus(); 
});

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<input type="button" id="demo_button" value="Click Me to open window with clean HTML TABLE prepared for copy"/>

<br/>This is HTML TABLE:
<TABLE id="test">
<TBODY>
<TR> <TD><b>TEXT 1</b></TD> <TD><a href="#">TEXT 2</a></TD> <TD><input  type="text" value="TEXT 3" ></TD> </TR>
<TR> <TD><span>TEXT 1.1</span></TD> <TD><a href="#">TEXT 2.1</a></TD> <TD><input  type="text" value="TEXT 3.1" ></TD> </TR>
</TBODY>
</TABLE>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

To extract just the text from something, use the `.text()` method. To get the value of an input, use the `.val()` method.

So, we need to loop over each `<TD>` cell, and within each of those, if there's an input, get the value out. We splice them together and put that back into the cell using the `.html()` method.

Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var tmp = '';
    $('table tbody tr td').each(function () {
        tmp = $(this).text();
        $(this).find('input').each(function () {
                tmp += $(this).val();
        });
        $(this).html(tmp);
    });
});
```

To learn more about jQuery's methods, see http://api.jquery.com/

Comment: I didn't type fast enough. Good answer.

Comment: It was a fun one, but I forgot my semicolons and had to edit.